# In Netty, How do I make a synchronous client call and return a result? (like apache components)

Tags: netty

In Netty, How do I make a synchronous client call and return a result? Here is how it works in Apache components:

```
HttpResponse response = httpRequester.execute();
```

I like that, I'd like to do that in Netty.

I try something like this, but how do I set the 'callable' return?

```
ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
f.awaitUninterruptibly();
HttpContent ans = (HttpContent) f.get();
```

Seems like that is the wrong path - dead end. Help/guidance please?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to use separate `ThreadPoolExecutor` for blocking operations. For example:

```
blockingIOProcessor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                HttpContent ans = (HttpContent) f.get();
                ctx.writeAndFlush(ans);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ctx.writeAndFlush("Error during blocking operation.");
            }
        });
```

Where `blockingIOProcessor` is the instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor`.
In the code above you are passing blocking operation to separate thread along with pipeline context. When blocking operation is finished you return the response back to calling pipeline via it context and your client receives request result.

In this case you are not blocking netty EventLoops.

Comment: Or just use the blocking ( old IO ) channel factory.